# Club's entry - "chain"

Tags: names

What is the name of the "chain" that can be found near club's entry?

e.g. http://www.vegasvipservices.com/nightclubs/bank/club-the-bank-entrance.jpg

Answer (score 10):

Those are referred to as *[velvet ropes](https://www.google.com/search?q=velvet%20ropes&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=iaB&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&prmd=imvns&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=961&bih=492&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=fi&ei=97zHT-2nMYv16AHj-ZAp)*.  Each pole is a type of *[stanchion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanchion)*:

> Stanchions are used for many different purposes including crowd
>   control & waiting lines. Many different places use stanchions
>   including banks, restaurants, trade shows and many different other
>   events.

Comment: For some reason, I like your answer better than I like @Lucas’s question. :)  I think it’s the *stanchion* that sold me.

Comment: According to this [site that sells the stuff (at the bottom)](http://stanchiondepot.com/classic.html) they refer to the ropes as "*stanchion rope*" or "*post rope*"